# Stanford CS106B C++ libraries in XCode 4

Tags: c++, include

I'm trying to use the Stanford CS106B C++ libraries, like simpio.h and genlib.h. I'm using XCode 4 (this is a beta version btw) and Mac OS X 10.6. I installed the libraries, but they don't seem to be showing up when I try to create a new project in XCode. Is there something different I should be doing with XCode 4 to get these libraries in?

There's probably a pretty basic solution to this problem, and if it were just a matter of frameworks in iOS, I could definitely get that to work with this version of XCode, but I've not really done this with C++ and XCode before, so I'm stuck.

Update on 7/20/11

I found a link to download the Xcode 2.5 tools as well as Xcode 3.0, both of which are described in the handout. I'm downloading both of them now. Does anyone know if Xcode 3.0 and 4.2 will run fine on the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, multiple versions of Xcode work fine together.  During the install, after the "Select a Destination" screen, you see a screen with the packages that will be installed.  Click "Developer" folder to change to a custom location for each different Xcode version.  The other tools (system and UNIX) cannot be moved.

After you have Xcode installed, just install your libraries in the usr/lib folder under your custom Xcode folder, and you should be good to go.

Comment: For anyone looking for the files they're here: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/materials/blank-mac-project.zip

Comment: I am too looking for the standard stanford libs for cs106b genlib/ simpleio ..the above link is broken -A

Comment: @Abhi you can download it from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/progabstrlib/files/